# How to embed an interactive shiny plot in a pdf / presentation? (via knitR maybe)

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, knitr, interactive

As the topic implies I am looking for a way to combine interactive shiny plots with knitr´s way of producing presentations/pdfs. 
The following intuitive approach should make my idea comprehensible.

````
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

sliderInput("bins",
        "Choose Standard Deviation:",
        min = 0,
        max = 2,
        value = 1,
        step = 0.1)
sliderInput("length",
        "Choose Length of Process:",
        min = 100,
        max = 10000,
        value = 1000,
        step = 100)

renderPlot({
    #create a random walk
    set.seed(12)
    y <- cumsum(rnorm(input$length,0,input$bins))
    plot(y, type="l") 
 })

```
````

I know it´s not a big deal to get that code into a html document, but is there a way to get the exact same thing (or at least close to that) in a pdf document?
So I want a pdf file with aN interactive plot. Is that somehow possible?
Many thanks in adavance :)

Comment: PDF are basically static documents, there is no way to achieve interactivity with PDF. Flash was highly interactive but flash is (almost) dead. If you can't use shiny you might try with HTML+embeddied js

Comment: thanks that´s already what I thought, just wanted to be absolutely sure to not oversee some trick. So the best would be to generate a pdf which is linked to the shiny html document, is that possible?

Comment: you can have a link in a PDF doc that opens your shiny app in the browser when clicked

Comment: thanks! That´s not what I hoped for but I will try it that way

Comment: If the app can be published online in advance, there can be a way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576359/559676

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from HubertL is basically the answer: it is not possible.