# Embeding shiny app in pdf latex (R knitr)

Tags: r, shiny, latex, knitr

I know that it's impossible to put shiny app in pdf latex directly, but I've heard ([How to embed an interactive shiny plot in a pdf / presentation? (via knitR maybe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561714/how-to-embed-an-interactive-shiny-plot-in-a-pdf-presentation-via-knitr-maybe) HubertL's answer) it's possible to bind it via link. Can someone help me with that? I haven't found anything about this. I'm using beamer Madrid (Idk if it's important).

Answer (score 1):

You have to publish the Shiny app first. Once you have got the URL to the online app, you can use `knitr::include_url()` to include an automatic screenshot of the app in non-HTML output formats. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/web-pages-and-shiny-apps.html for more information.

Note that this feature currently requires the **webshot** package and PhantomJS:

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```